# Aggregate multiple fields in one rethinkdb query

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

How to reduce / aggregate multiple fields in a table? This does not seem efficient:

```
r.object(
  'favorite_count', 
  r.db('twitterdb').table('tweets').map(tweet => tweet('favorite_count')).avg().round(),
  'retweet_count',
   r.db('twitterdb').table('tweets').map(tweet => tweet('retweet_count')).avg().round()
  )
```

(Expected) Result:

```
{

    "favorite_count": 17 ,
    "retweet_count": 156

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible to make RethinkDB work like you want in one go using its built-ins, but you can implement the `avg` function yourself really easy:

```
r.db('twitterdb')
  .table('tweets')
  .fold(
    {_: 0, favorite_count: 0, retweet_count: 0},
    (a, tweet) => ({
      _: a('_').add(1),
      favorite_count: a('favorite_count').add(tweet('favorite_count')),
      retweet_count: a('retweet_count').add(tweet('retweet_count'))
    })
  )
  .do(a => ({
    favorite_count: r.branch(a('_').gt(0), a('favorite_count').div(a('_')).round(), null),
    retweet_count: r.branch(a('_').gt(0), a('retweet_count').div(a('_')).round(), null)
  }))
```

I have quickly-tested the above over a small set of data, and enabling the query profiling showed at least /2 shard accesses and less time to execute.
However I'm not sure about the overall profiler output and I don't think I can interpret its details (I believe that native `avg` is more optimized, but it looks cheaper that accesing the data at least in two rounds).
Additionally, this custom *avg* function implementation is more 0-elements friendly not throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the array is known (e.g. `7430`), this is faster:

```
  r.db('twitterdb').table('tweets')
  .reduce((agg, item) => {
    return {
      favorite_count: agg('favorite_count').add(item('favorite_count')),
      retweet_count: agg('retweet_count').add(item('retweet_count'))
      }
    })
   .do(result => r.object('favorite_count', result('favorite_count').div(7430).round(), 'retweet_count', result('retweet_count').div(7430).round()))
```